# Why are the values in the array retained in the while loop? (VB.NET)

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, parsing, file-io

If I place a breakpoint at the line `currentrow = MyParser.ReadFields()`
, currentrow still contains the values of the previous line parsed from the file. After `currentrow = MyParser.ReadFields()`
 executes, the current file line values are stored.

Since currentrow is declared inside the While loop, shouldn't the previous currentrow value be out of scope when re-entering the While loop? Why does currentrow still retain values from the last line in the file?

Do I need to change `Dim currentrow As String()`
 to `Dim currentRow() = New String() {}`? Why?

```
If File.Exists(filename) Then
        Using MyParser As New FileIO.TextFieldParser(filename)
            MyParser.TextFieldType = FileIO.FieldType.Delimited
            MyParser.SetDelimiters("~")
            While Not MyParser.EndOfData
                Try
                    Dim currentrow As String()
                    'at this point, currentrow still contains prev values
                    currentrow = MyParser.ReadFields()
                Catch 
                End Try
            End While
        End Using
End If
```

Comment: This is a bad use of File.Exists(). Just open the file and handle a FileNotFoundException instead.

Comment: Also, is necessarily bad that currentrow still has old values, as long as you structure the loop correctly?

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn: Can you give me some more information as to the difference between catching the exception or checking with File.Exists() and why the latter is not as good?

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn: Imho it's bad because most people don't know that it contains old values if they only declare an variable in a loop. That might work in 999 cases where the code looks like above, but in one case somebody does anything with currentrow before the new value is assigned.

Comment: @user1620141 The file system is _volatile_... checking File.Exists() makes no guarantees the file will still be there a few moments later when you actually go to use it... meaning you still have to watch for the exception, so it's wasted code. File.Exists() also does nothing to guarantee you have permissions, or whether the file is locked, and it also means an extra trip out to disk (about the slowest thing possible for a computer to do). The only time you should use File.Exists() is when the very existence of a file can trigger something in your code without you needing to ever open the file.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn: That's interesting. Thanks for the information. This brings another question to mind. In my code above, if the file is modified in the middle of parsing, will that cause any issues? For example, when I have a text file open and someone modifies it elsewhere, it does not have any adverse effects on my reading the file. Will the parser work the same way?

Comment: It depends on the file is opened. I don't recall what FileMode and sharing options the TextFieldParser uses, but you can set a file to not be shared such that anyone else trying to open or write to the fail would fail until you are finished. Otherwise, it depends on what they modify when on what will happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you have only declared the loop variable, as against this which results in a correct value of `Nothing` on every iteration:

```
Dim currentrow As String() = Nothing
```

or even better

```
Dim currentrow As String() = MyParser.ReadFields()
```

"Dim" by itself, without the explicit initialization, will be optimized out as redundant.

Even if you assign `Nothing`, it will always be reset to `Nothing` on every iteration. If you only declare the variable it will always contain the "wrong" old value even if you would use `Console.Write` or `MessageBox.Show` afterwards.

So always assign a default value in a loop variable to avoid side-effects.

**Sidenote** C# avoids this error source with the [compiler warning CS0165](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4y7h161d%28v=vs.80%29.aspx): *Use of unassigned local variable 'variablename'*.

So if you would try to use that unassigned variable before it gets assigned you would not even be able to compile with C#. I don't know why VB.NET allows it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So is currentrow not recreated in each iteration of the loop? To clarify, the very 1st time we step into the loop, currentrow is declared. Why then, does it not get redeclared each iteration of the loop thereafter?

Comment: @user1620141: I would like to show you a language specification or blog, but unfortunately i don't find anything. `currentrow` will be reassigned at `currentrow = MyParser.ReadFields()`, not on the declaration line since that will be "optimized out"/omitted because it's redundant in  a loop. But it could be a source of errors.

Answer (score 1):

Remember that all variables in VB have a scope of the block they're declared in, but a lifetime of the whole routine(*) (effectively from where they are declared to the end of the routine), and they're always initialised to `Nothing`, whatever that means for the actual type.

```
Dim outer As Integer
For i = 1 To 2
 Dim inner As Integer
 Try
  Dim inner2 As Integer
  Do
   Dim inner3 As Integer
   While True
    Dim inner4 As Integer
    Console.WriteLine(outer & ", " & inner & ", " & inner2 & ", " & inner3 & ", " & inner4)
    outer = i
    inner = i
    inner2 = i
    inner3 = i
    inner4 = i
    Exit While
   End While
  Loop Until True
 Catch
 End Try
Next
```

The above outputs:

```
0, 0, 0, 0, 0
1, 1, 1, 1, 1
```

(*)Anonymous routines/closures affect this. See my [separate question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13266748/256431).

Comment: Thanks for the example and link to your question. Out of curiosity, do you know if this behavior is exclusive to VB.NET or would the output be the same in C#?

Comment: C# doesn't allow you to access variables before they're assigned.