# Why don't all of these variables get treated the same way?

Tags: vb.net, closures

I was checking that the position of variable declarations in VB.NET don't matter, except for scope, (for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13259999/256431)) and I thought I better check what happens when they're "lifted" into a closure. I haven't read the spec, but I can't explain these results:

```
Dim outer As Integer
For i = 1 To 2
 Dim inner As Integer
 Try
  Dim inner2 As Integer
  Do
   Dim inner3 As Integer
   Call Sub()
    Dim inner4 As Integer
    Console.WriteLine(outer & ", " & inner & ", " & inner2 & ", " & inner3 & ", " & inner4)
    outer = i
    inner = i
    inner2 = i
    inner3 = i
    inner4 = i
   End Sub()
  Loop Until True
 Finally
 End Try
Next
```

The above outputs:

```
0, 0, 0, 0, 0
1, 1, 0, 1, 0
```

`inner4` being reset each time makes sense, as would all or none of the other `innerX`, but why only `inner2`?!

Comment: What does Call Sub() do exactly?

Comment: @AhmadAl-Mutawa Fair enough question. An expanded version is `Dim closure = Sub()...End Sub : closure()` and I've tested it and the results are the same.

Comment: I think that `inner3` is the interesting one rather than `inner2`. I think it should be 0.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Yeah, given that `inner2` is reset, I definitely can't see why `inner3` isn't. And clearly the `Try` is "special", which is why there's a difference between `inner` and `inner2`. I've also tested a `Try` outside the `For` loop and a variable declared there has the same behaviour as `outer`.

Answer (score 2):

From MSDN (emphasis mine) :

> [...]what the compiler basically does, when it enters a new scope containing a lifted variable, the compiler will check to see if an instance of closure already exists; if so, the compiler will create a new instance of closure and reset the value of the variable from the previous closure.
>
> Note that the compiler only does the above check ***if it detects a loop or a GoTo in the function where the closure is generated***.

[Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb981314%28VS.80%29.aspx)

Comment: As I said in the answer where the simple (non-closure) version of this code comes from, the _scope_ is the block where the declaration is, but the _lifetime_ is  the whole routine. Do you have any reference for what is happening in the closure?

Comment: @MarkHurd - sorry for being vague, it was an old memory I'd poorly parsed into an answer.  I found a reference for you.

Comment: +1 so far, as you've determined two things: VB is doing something "special" here, and looking at this code in Reflector will probably confirm what is happening.

Comment: @MarkHurd - yes, reflector would answer it.  I think it looks like a weak attempt to retain non-closure-like behaviour when using anonymous methods.  The compiler should probably do this when entering any new scope block inside a loop rather than just for the loop blocks.  It may be limited by recursion issues perhaps?

Answer (score 2):

(This is more a comment, but in need of too much code to keep it as one.)

Reflector does show *what* is happening:

```
<STAThread> _
Public Shared Sub Main()
Dim e$__ As New _Closure$__1
Try 
    Dim e$__2 As New _Closure$__2
    Dim e$__3 As New _Closure$__3
    e$__3.$VB$Local_i = 1
    Do
        Dim e$__4 As _Closure$__4
        e$__4 = New _Closure$__4(e$__4)
        Try 
            Dim e$__5 As New _Closure$__5
            Do
                Dim e$__6 As _Closure$__6
                e$__6 = New _Closure$__6(e$__6)
                e$__6.$VB$NonLocal_$VB$Closure_ClosureVariable_8_5 = e$__5
                e$__6.$VB$NonLocal_$VB$Closure_ClosureVariable_6_4 = e$__4
                e$__6.$VB$NonLocal_$VB$Closure_ClosureVariable_6_6 = e$__3
                e$__6.$VB$NonLocal_$VB$Closure_ClosureVariable_4_4 = e$__2
                e$__6.$VB$NonLocal_$VB$Closure_ClosureVariable_2_B = e$__
                Dim e_ As VB$AnonymousDelegate_0 = New VB$AnonymousDelegate_0(AddressOf e$__6._Lambda$__1)
                e_.Invoke
            Loop While (0 <> 0)
        End Try
        e$__3.$VB$Local_i += 1
    Loop While (e$__3.$VB$Local_i <= 2)
End Try
End Sub
```

<sub>(This is based upon my code which includes a `Try` outside the `For`.)</sub>

You can see here the `For` loop (seen as a `Do` loop with the `$VB$Local_i` set before) and the inner `Do` generate closures that do have the previous instance of the closure passed in, but the `Try` does not get that treatment.

Still don't know *why*? Looks like a bug to me. If I don't get a reasonable "excuse" (:-)) in a day or so I'll put it on Connect. (Can someone confirm .NET 4.5 VB11 performs the same?)

Comment: Via LinqPad 5 beta, this has been fixed in VB.NET 14: The second line is now `1, 1, 1, 1, 0`.

Comment: just an idea!! because variables declared inside a try block are invisible outside of it, and the way system treat exceptions, makes the call sub looks like it is outside the block. thus the variable inner2 is not that in the call sub block. try using call sub(var) and pass inner2 as a parameter for the call sub.

Comment: @milevyo I'm sure there are workarounds, but that the later version "fixes" this suggests it should have been that way all along.